process_tweet and build_freqs
I am unable to import process_tweet and build_freqs into JupyterLab notebook for use in natural language processing. I have checked previous recommendations on stackoverflow for the resolution of this issue. None seems to work. Kindly assist.

I figured it out. I did not need to use the JupyterLab on my machine. A template was provided and the codes in that template all worked.
